# php iCalCreator - undefined method DateTime::setTimestamp()

Tags: php, icalendar

I'm trying to use the practical [iCalCreator](http://kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator) class version 2.12 (which allows to create iCal data for scheduling applications) with php 5.2.17

This simple code

```
require_once('iCalcreator.class.php');

$config = array('unique_id' => 'xxxxxxx.net');
$v = new vcalendar($config);
$tz = "Europe/Paris";
$v->setProperty('method', 'PUBLISH');
$v->setProperty("x-wr-calname", "Calendar Sample");
$v->setProperty("X-WR-CALDESC", "Calendar Description");
$v->setProperty("X-WR-TIMEZONE", $tz);
$xprops = array("X-LIC-LOCATION" => $tz);
iCalUtilityFunctions::createTimezone($v, $tz, $xprops);
$vevent = & $v->newComponent('vevent');
```

Gives this error (occurring at the last line):

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DateTime::setTimestamp() in /home/httpd/html/default/v8/mod_report/include/iCalcreator.class.php on line 7257

The [doc says](http://kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/docs/using.html)

> Development environment is PHP version 5.x but coding is done to meet 4.x backward compatibility and may work. Some functions requires PHP >= 5.2.0.

[`DateTime::setTimestamp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php) seems to have been implemented since php 5.3.0

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Aren't you kind of answering your own question? :)

Comment: I'm trying to make sure that the doc is incorrect and that I have to update my php version. Maybe there is a known work around for this problem with iCalCreator.

Comment: ah, I see, it's about the product, I didn't catch that, sorry. Well, the manual page you link to provides one workaround - you could use that if you're ready to alter the product's source code

Comment: Are you talking about the "...timezone need to be set/altered..." ? I didn't understand this info because it's already set in the source. It's doing the same error if I change it

Comment: The manual has `Example #2 DateTime::setTimestamp() alternative in PHP 5.2` you'd need to replace the call with the alternative.

Comment: Ok I didn't see that. It's working. I changed 3 lines in the class (7235, 7243, 7258) You can put an answer that I will accept and I will modify for putting the code.